# Write quotes to a text file using ofstream, c++

Tags: c++, ofstream

I want to write out quotes to be in the file and I don't know how the syntax should look.

```
ofstream file("myfile.txt");
    if ( file.is_open())
    {
        file << "\n";
        file << ""type of file""<< "=" << '\n'; // obviously this is wrong
        file << "name = \n";
    }
```

I want the text file to look like so:

> "type of file" =
>
> name =

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\"` instead of just `"`, i.e.:

```
file << "\n"; // note not "/n"
file << "\"type of file\"" << "=" << "\n";
file << "name = \n";
```

Of course the middle line could just be:

```
file << "\"type of file\"=\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to escape the `"` with `\` so `\"`

```
file << "\"type of file\""<< "=" << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the escape character

```
file << "\"type of file\"" << "=" << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ofstream file("myfile.txt")) 
{ 
    file << "/n" 
            "\"type of file\"=\n"
            "name = \n"; 
}
```